# State and postal code fields are not populating based on the selection of country with addressfield module and commerce drupal 7

Tags: commerce, entities

I am using Addressfield module with Drupal commerce in shipping and billing section. I have a requirement to display the country dropdown only the country where user is on means when user shops in United states cart, then the shipping section country dropdown should display only United states as value. For this i added addressfield_standard_form_alter function and code looks like below

```
function exigo_order_integration_field_widget_addressfield_standard_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, &$context) {

  // Only for shipping section
  if ($element['#entity']->type == "shipping") {
    $countryOptions = array();
    // Build the country option from session which contains session value of user country currently on
    $countryOptions[$_SESSION['exigo_settings_current_country']] = $element['country']['#options'][$_SESSION['exigo_settings_current_country']];

    $countryOptions['TT'] = "Trinidad & Tobago";

    $handlers = array('address' => 'address');
    $context = array('mode' => 'form');

    $address = array(
      'country' => $_SESSION['exigo_settings_current_country'],
      'name_line' => '',
      'first_name' => '',
      'last_name' => '',
      'organisation_name' => '',
      'administrative_area' => '',
      'sub_administrative_area' => '',
      'locality' => '',
      'dependent_locality' => '',
      'postal_code' => '',
      'thoroughfare' => '',
      'premise' => '',
      'sub_premise' => '',
      'data' => '',
    );

    // Regenerate the addressfield to properly show province, postal code, etc
    $address_rendered = addressfield_generate($address, $handlers, $context);

    // Assign the newly generated field to the element
    $element['street_block'] = $address_rendered['street_block'];
    $element['locality_block'] = $address_rendered['locality_block'];
    $element['country'] = $address_rendered['country'];

    // Override the country option list
    $element['country']['#options'] = $countryOptions;
  }
```

I added 'Trinidad & Tobago' country to the dropdown and selection of this country the address section is not re-generating. If i remove the above function then again all country get displayed in country dropdown and everything will work fine. What i doing wrong here or what additional changes need to do to populate state and postal code based on country selection?

Any help will be really appreciated